# Spring Boot 3, Hibernate 6 How to aggregate a Value Object?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a data model with Value Objects. Normal queries work without problems. But now I want to use for example the SQL functions "SUM()", "MIN()" and so on. I can't manage this. How can I achieve this with a Value Object.
Example:

```
@Query("""
    SELECT
        r.year AS year,
        r.type AS type,
        SUM(s.amount) AS sum
    FROM
        Receipt r JOIN r.sumLines s 
    GROUP BY r.year, r.type
    ORDER BY r.year, r.type
    """)
List<DocumentsYearTypeSum> documentsByYearTypeSum();
```

The select works when there is only `s.amount AS sum`, but as soon as I use the `SUM()` function, I get the error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.query.ReturnableType.getExpressibleJavaType()" because "this.type" is null
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.function.SelfRenderingFunctionSqlAstExpression.createDomainResult(SelfRenderingFunctionSqlAstExpression.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.lambda$visitSelection$25(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2053) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonList.forEach(Collections.java:4966) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelection(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:2048) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelectClause(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1951) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQuerySpec(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1819) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQuerySpec(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:416) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmQuerySpec.accept(SqmQuerySpec.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.spi.BaseSemanticQueryWalker.visitQueryPart(BaseSemanticQueryWalker.java:213) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQueryPart(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1679) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelectStatement(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1477) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitSelectStatement(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:416) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmSelectStatement.accept(SqmSelectStatement.java:213) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.translate(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:711) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.buildCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:380) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:571) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.list(QuerySqmImpl.java:1073) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:127) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:148) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy175.documentsByYearTypeSum(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by previously casting

```
SUM(cast(s.amount as BigDecimal)) AS sum
```